# Matlab compare elements of a big Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, compare

I have a big Matrix with the size `(1000,1000,20)`

I have to compare the elements at Position `(x,y,1)` with `(x,y,2)` and `(x,y,3)` and so on till `(x,y,20)` to find the minimum, and the index where the minimum is.

In the end I want `2` new matrices with size `(1000,1000,1)`: one with the minimum Element, and one with the index where the minimum was.

For example I have:

```
A(:,:,1)=[1,2;2,4]

A(:,:,2)=[0,3;1,2]
```

I want to get the matrices:

```
X = [0,2;2,4]
```

and:

```
Y=[2,1;1,1]
```

with the index information.

I can solve it with a loop, but would like to use a more time efficient method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your example needs to be rewritten, but the built-in min function will do the trick:

```
[C,I] = min(A,[],3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`min`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/min.html) function for this.

When used in this way:

```
[C, I] = min(A, [], dim)
```

it returns the smallest elements along the given dimension `dim` in `C` and their indices in `I`.

The returned indices are linear indices, which you can turn into subscripts using [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) for each index.